# Gradle / Maven: How to use in-developement dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, gradle

**Context:**

I'm working on a Gradle project which depends on external libraries, also created by me. Currently I was usign a simple dependecy on `project(':lib')`.

But this is not enough anymore, I need to release and distribute libraries as standalone components, versionned and documented. I will install Apache Archiva and publish them to an internal maven repository, so I can depend explicitly on `'com.company:lib:1.0'`.

**Question:**

During developement, I will work on libraries and on projects at the same time. How can I test my code without publishing the libraries ? My application which used to depend on `project()` will now depend on a specific version. But while developing, I would like to use the local code.

Do you know what is the best process to handle this ?

Comment: You can build a snapshot version and publish it on the maven. Usually each maven has a release (stable) and snapshot repository.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti This mean I have to upload the snapshot version everytime I do a modification ?

Comment: In the machine you can always use compile project (:xxx). But if you need to share with a team during the dev the snapshot could be a good way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer to this question is available in [Gradle's documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) (section `23.8.3.1`), and is the following:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        substitute module("com.company:lib") with project(":lib")
        substitute module("com.company:lib2") with project(":lib2")
    }
}
```

Personally, I used the following code, which makes all `-SNAPSHOT` versions to be taken from local projects instead of remote repository (if a local project is available):

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.dependencySubstitution {
        all { dependency ->
            if (! dependency.requested.version.endsWith('SNAPSHOT'))
                return
            if (subprojects.find { p ->p.name == dependency.requested.module })
                dependency.useTarget project(":" + dependency.requested.module)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to add the dependency conditionally.  So for your local builds (IDE) you want to build the dependency via source.  Then you can distinguish your release builds by having your releases pass a param to a build.

```
dependencies {
    if (project.hasProperty('release')) {
        compile 'com.company:lib:1.0'
    } else {
        compile project(':lib')
    }
}
```

Then in your release builds to use the lib from nexus:
`$ gradle -Prelease=true clean build`

If you want to build the project with the lib from inside the project:
`$ gradle clean build`